# Late variable problem & instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, initializer, userid

I am trying to pass the user.uid from the NavigationPage to ProfilePage. BUT I get this error message under **late** ("Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name. Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'") and this error message under **user** ("The instance member 'user' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"). I am using the following code:

```
class NavScreen extends StatefulWidget {

   _NavScreenState createState() => _NavScreenState();

}

class _NavScreenState extends State<NavScreen> {

   late final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

   final List<Widget> _screens = [

      ProfileScreen(profileId: user.uid),

   ];

}
```

Any ideas on a possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `_screens` a `late` variable as well and you should be fine.

```
late final List<Widget> _screens
```

You can't declare a property that requires another property from the same instance which hasn't yet been initialised.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the quick response. Doing what you suggested solves the "user problem", so that good! Now, I still have the "late problem". The error message for "late final user" is ("Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name. Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'"), and the error for "late final List<Widget> _screens" is ("Unexpected text 'late'. Try removing the text."). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you have to migrate to null safety in order to be able to use the late keyword

[here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) is the dart migration guide

Comment: Hello! So just to double check: in order for me to use late I have to migrate my whole code to null safety? Is it possible to only migrate part of the code (instead of the whole code)? Also, do you think it is worthwhile to migrate to null safety? Thanks